# How to write this SQL query in JPQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I'm looking to convert the following SQL into JPQL:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    rooms
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(        
    SELECT  *
    FROM    booking, booking_has_rooms
    WHERE   rooms.number=booking_has_rooms.rooms_number AND 
            booking.booking_id=booking_has_rooms.booking_booking_id AND 
            :date BETWEEN booking.checkin AND booking.checkout
);
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT rooms 
FROM Rooms rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT bk 
    FROM Booking b 
    JOIN  b.roomsCollection bk 
    WHERE :date BETWEEN b.checkin AND b.checkout
)
```

It returns all the rooms correctly if no bookings are on the specified date.
However if any bookings are on the specified date - it does not return any rooms at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a clause in the inner query:

```
SELECT rooms 
FROM Rooms rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT bk 
    FROM Booking b 
    JOIN  b.roomsCollection bk 
    WHERE :date BETWEEN b.checkin AND b.checkout
    and bk.id = rooms.id
)
```

Your code would be much clearer if you renamed Rooms to Room. Each instance is a single room, so it should use the singular form.